# Multiple labels on ipycytoscape nodes in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter, cytoscape, ipycytoscape

Is it possible to add multiple labels on an ipycytoscape node? Or, alternatively, make the css 'content' element take a function?

For example, I have nodes defined as follows:

```
network= '''{
    "nodes": [
        {"data": {"id": "MOD1022", "amp":"67", "classes":"data"}},
         
         ...  // more nodes

        ],
    "edges": [
        ...
    ]
  }'''
```

I want the nodes to show both the `id` and the `amp` values. By reading [this](https://ipycytoscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/node-text.html) I am able to add node labels with either `id` or `amp`. But is there a way to somehow have the label be a combination of both?